# Enforce no-delay schedule IBM OPL (CPLEX)

Tags: scheduling, cplex, opl

I created a schedule in IBM OPL:

```
dvar sequence schedule in all(j in Jobs) job[j];
```

If the CP-Module generates a solution, the solution is sometimes not a non-delay solution. This is however not allowed and thus I want to enforce a non-delay schedule.

I tried different solutions in the subject to-Section...

```
 forall(t in Jobs)
   if (t > 1)
   startOf(job[t]) == endOf(job[t-1]);
```

... but these fail (obviously) when job t-1 is not followed by job t.

Anyone who can give me a hint on how to solve this problem?

Kind regards,
Franz

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by a non-delay solution. But I am guessing that there are gaps in your schedule when nothing is happening? The "standard" way of fixing that used to be to minimise the end time of the whole schedule. In the CP model, you can always create a zero duration job that can only happen after all the other jobs. Then you can look at the solution and you should be able to set the end of that final task to its earliest possible time and the CP model should then propagate that decision to update the start times of all the other jobs.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to use endAtStart.
(OPL constraint to restrict the relative positions of interval variables.)
regards

Comment: Could you give a little more detail?
If I use endAtStart(schedule, job[t], job[t-1]) it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

**endAtStart** will only work if your Jobs are always ready to start when the preceding Job finishes. If this is not the case, you will receive an error.

A better solution would be to regard the no-delay in the objective. What you are trying to achieve is to start every new job as soon as possible. So you can for example use the **staticLex** function:

```
minimize staticLex(startOf(job[1]), startOf(job[2]),...);
```

However, this expression can become very long and you would need to hardcode the number of intervals.
A little workaround would be to assign the intervals **decreasing weighting factors**:

```
minimize sum(j in Jobs) startOf(job[j])*100^-ord(Jobs,j);
```

I hope this works for you!

Regards
Jan